# Iterating over an array and dictionary and storing the values in another array

Tags: python, arrays

Say I have a dictionary of pattern types:

```
patternDict = {1:[0],5:[0,3]}
```

And I have an array:

```
A = [[1,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9]]
```

I also have two empty arrays to store the value of each pattern type:

```
pattern1=[]
pattern5=[]
```

I am iterating over each row in A and each pattern type in patternDict:

```
for row in A:
    for key, value in patternDict.iteritems():
        currentPattern = row[value] for value in patternDict[key]
        #append either pattern1 or pattern5 with currentPattern based on the key
```

And this is where I am having trouble. How do I append to either the Pattern 1 array or Pattern 5 array based on the key in patternDict. The output would look like:

```
pattern1=[1,6]
pattern5=[1,5,6,9]
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: How does `pattern5` end up as `[1, 4, 6, 8]` ?

Comment: What does the inner `for` loop have to do with the contents of the rows of `A`?

Comment: @JonClements, I added currentPattern to show.

Comment: What's `rows`? Please provide *actual* code, not pseudo-code.

Comment: `pattern5` shoule be `[1,5,6,9]`?

Comment: `currentPattern = row[value] for value in patternDict[key]` is not a valid statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use `dict` instead of variables](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html):

```
>>> p = {k:[x[y] for x in A for y in v] for k, v in patterrnDict.iteritems()}
>>> p[1]
[1, 6]
>>> p[5]
[1, 5, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the constraints you've specified, the solution is actually pretty simple.

```
for row in rows:
    for key, value in patternDict.iteritems():
        currentPattern = [row[value] for value in patternDict[key]]
        if key == 1:
            pattern1.extend(currentPattern)
        elif key == 5:
            pattern5.extend(currentPattern)
```

But I suspect that your **real** problem is not so closely related to simplified problem. If you can provide a clearer description, someone will provide an appropriate generalization.

Comment: Yeah, the only difference is that I actually have 10 pattern types and 10 arrays.

Comment: And what are their names?

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend using a `dict`, too, as in *hcwhsa*'a reply, and if you have just a few such variables, you could also use an `if-else` condition, as in *Rob*'s answer.

However, if there's *abolutely no way around* using separate variables for the different lists instead of one `dict`, you could access those variables using the `globals()` function. This function returns a dictionary mapping the names of all the variable and functions defined in the current scope to their respective values, i.e., `globals()["foo"]` gets you the content of the variable `foo`.

```
for row in A:
    for key, value in patternDict.iteritems():
        currentPattern = [row[value] for value in patternDict[key]]
        globals()["pattern%d" % key].extend(currentPattern)
print pattern1, pattern5
```

But be warned that this can lead to all sorts of nasty, hard to detect bugs and should generally be avoided!